# Describe the embeddings of L extending σ1, and the embeddings of L extending σ2. Which are real and which are complex? What is the signature of L?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Let $K = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$
and let $\alpha = 1 + \sqrt2.$ Let $\beta =
\sqrt\alpha$ and $L = \Bbb{Q}(\beta).$
I've already shown that the embeddings of K can be
labelled as $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ in such a way that $\sigma_1(\alpha) > 0$ and $\sigma_2(\alpha) < 0$; and  $\beta\notin K$. How do I describe the embeddings of $L$ extending $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$? How do I even know that $L/K$ is an extension of $L$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I TeXified your post. Just to show you how easy it is :-). It becomes progressively more useful, the more complicated your formulas become, and LaTeX is the *lingua franca* for typesetting math. Do take the time learn the local dialect from the links in the comment above. It will help you in "real life" as well! You may also benefit from taking a look at [our abridged guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619). Observing those guidelines to the applicable extent will enhance your experience on this site.